# What should I use to run a pre and post after intervention with a control group 15 participants?

Tags: t-test

I want to know the effect of reflective video analysis on teacher intentions to stay or leave the teaching position, teacher efficacy, and teacher job satisfaction in rural middle schools.  I will have a control group (without random assignment) and a non control group. Both groups will complete a pre and post likert scale survey measuring teachers intention to stay or leave the position, teacher efficacy,and teacher job satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

From your survey, develop a single-score for each of the following. (ex, if there are three survey questions pertaining to teaching efficacy, average them all together..etc)

1a) teacher intentions to stay or leave the teaching position
1b) teacher efficacy
1c) and teacher job satisfaction

every person will have both pre and post scores for 1a) 1b) and 1c)

take the difference between pre and post for each person. (eg. (post score) - (pre score)

your data should look something like this

Person   group         1a)Change    1b)Change    1c)Change
  1      control          -2            -5           2
  2      control           2            -2           3
  3      treatment        -1             1          -1
...        ...            ...            ...        ...

all you have to do now is run 3 separate t-tests using "group" as the x variable and each of the other variables separately as the y variable.

hope this helps!

MRstats

Comment: I just realized that the format of my answer is horrible. Msg me if you want me to send you a better formatted version.